# jQuery wait for .each to finish and run ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
var allChecks = [];
$('input[type=text]').each(function () {
    var key = $(this).attr("id");
    allChecks[key] = [];
}).promise()
        .done(function () {
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    var ref = $(this).attr('id');
                    $('.' + ref).each(function () {
                        allChecks[ref].push({
                            amount: $("#" + ref).text()
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    allChecks[ref].push({
                        amount: 0.00
                    });
                }
            }).promise()
                    .done(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            cache: false,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {
                                allChecks: allChecks
                            },
                            url: '/process',
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                console.log("Processing your checks please wait...");
                            },
                            success: function (response) {
                                console.log(response);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                console.log("Error");
                            }
                        });
                    });
        });
```

My Ajax call runs but I see no data passed as parameters, like if the array allChecks is empty. As JavaScript runs synchronously, I'm expecting that whatever I place after each() will not run until each() is complete, so the Ajax call should run fine and nor give me no data passed as if the array allChecks is empty. Any help or solution on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is with the promise() supposed to be doing? makes no sense to have it after the each calls. each() is synchronous so the values would be applied...

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/promise/ this method seems to be create a promise which is resolved when all _animations_ on elements in a collection have completed. We can't see if your inputs have animations on them, but it seems safe to guess they haven't, so your promise will likely resolve immediately ("Using .promise() on a collection with no active animation returns a resolved Promise:"). Your code would have been synchronous and worked nicely without using promises, but you seem to have made it (potentially) async for no obvious reason?

Comment: Also, `allChecks[ref].push({
            amount: 0.00
          });` will never work because ref is not defined at that time. And I can't see your HTML but `if (this.checked) {
            var ref = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.' + ref).each(function() {
              allChecks[ref].push({
                amount: $("#" + ref).text()
              });
            });` doesn't make much sense. If the checkbox is checked, you get its ID, and then loop some more elements which have that class. Each time you find one, you add to allChecks[ref] ...

Comment: ...but allChecks[ref] should not exist, because HTML IDs must be unique, and you created the elements of allChecks with references based on the IDs of the _textboxes_, not the _checkboxes_. They can't (or at least shouldn't match). Also, `$('.' + ref).each(function() {`...what are these elements? How many can there be? Why would you push the same "amount" object into allChecks[ref] multiple times? It doesn't look right at all but without the HTML I can't prove it. I'd be quite surprised if you don't have some console errors about undefined elements, though.

Comment: Theoretical demo showing the issues: https://jsfiddle.net/3gwr1ao1/9/ (Obviously I had to invent a HTML structure, so that part is guesswork). P.S. Correction to my earlier comment - you code wouldn't have "worked nicely" without the promises bit, because of these problems, but equally, since JS is synchronous as you point out, there appears to be no need for the promises either - unless you've got timed animations running on your elements, they're completely redundant.

Comment: Sorry for the promiss and done methods that got you confused. It was an attempt to solve why my ajax request sends no parameters.

Comment: No, the likely reason it sends an empty dataset is due to the logical errors I've outlined above. Without knowing your HTML or your true intention it's hard to provide a definitive fixed version, though.

Comment: I posted a full code with my issue in a new topic and voted to close this topic as I think it is not clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999292/ajax-not-sending-data-as-parameters