# Ajax not sending data as parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an array via ajax so I have the following code:

Here is the code

```js
function fncGetChecksToProcess() {
  var allChecks = [];
  $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
    var key = $(this).attr("id").replace("txt_", "");
    allChecks[key] = [];
  });
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      var className = $(this).attr('class');
      if (className.includes('box_total_')) {
        var ref = $(this).attr('id').replace("box_total_", "");
        var amountDetails = [];
        var docNs = [];
        $('.' + ref).each(function() {
          amountDetails.push(parseFloat($(this).closest('td').next().html().replace("$", "").replace(",", "")));
          docNs.push($(this).attr('id').replace("box_", ""));
        });
        allChecks[ref].push({
          docN: docNs,
          amountTot: $("#sub_" + ref).text(),
          amountDetails: amountDetails,
          chkNum: $("#txt_" + ref).val()
        });
      } else {
        var docN = $(this).attr('id').replace("box_", "");
        allChecks[className].push({
          docN: docN,
          amountTot: $("#td_" + docN).text(),
          amountDetails: "",
          chkNum: $("#txt_" + className).val()
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return allChecks;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    var checks = fncGetChecksToProcess();
    console.log(checks);
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        allChecks: checks
      },
      url: '/process',
      beforeSend: function() {
        console.log("Processing your checks please wait...");
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="table" class="tablesorter" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>H1</th>
        <th>H2</th>
        <th>H3</th>
        <th>H4</th>
        <th>H5</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>H6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>11002WR</td>
        <td>201100</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="center"><input class="11002WR" id="box_201100" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td id="td_201100">$320.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td>Check. No</td>
        <td><input id="txt_11002WR" type="text"></td>
        <td><input id="box_total_11002WR" class="box_total_201100" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td id="sub_11002WR">$12.00</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input id="btn" type="button" value="Test" />
</body>

</html>
```

Please check the two checkboxes and the input and press on the test.

The console prints out the array generated but Ajax does not send it.

Why my ajax call does not send any parameters? I don't see them in chrome console.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI you can use `$("input[type=checkbox]:checked")` so you don't need `if(this.checked)`

Comment: thanks for the hint. Any ideas why I'm having the ajax issue

Comment: No, haven't figured that part out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your keys are strings, not numbers, you should be using an object, not an array. Change

```
var allChecks = [];
```

to

```
var allChecks = {};
```

When you send an array with `$.ajax`, it only sends the elements with numeric indexes, not named properties.

Comment: Seems JS arrays can be given string indexes, as long as they're numeric. As mentioned above though, it creates a sparse array

Comment: Could that be the reason of the ajax issue?

Comment: @Phil But his indexes aren't numeric, they're things like `11002WR`

Comment: @oussamakamal Yes, that's why I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I missed that one. Some are stripped of their non-numeric prefixes though and become numbers (edit: well, one is... `box_201100`)

Comment: Yes, by changing var allChecks = []; to var allChecks = {}; it worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to send an array to ajax , now you send an array of array inside array... 
if you post to the server like form the post will looks like:

```
allchecks[] = x
allchecks[] = y ...
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/SnZmKgRLODYb8p6kPryn?p=preview

```
   $.ajax({

          cache: false,
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
            allChecks: checks["11002WR"][0]
          },
```

this is a fast solution for you . but it is not a good practice

instead of allchecks=[] . try to build objects with keys or ids and not string like the ref as a key of the array

objects is like the following :

```
 var allChecks = {};
```